# Cipher.doFinal trims data size when using AES/CBC/PKCS7

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to perform AES encryption on Android. I use the `cipher.doFinal()` method to encrypt the data. This works fine for smaller data, but fails when I use it on large data. When trying to encrypt large data e.g byte array with length 200k, my end result is a byte array with length of 70k. This is less than half of the original data size. Also, when decrypting the same image, I can confirm my result. The decrypted image is only 1/3 of the original. Strangely, no call to cipher throws any exceptions e.g illegal block size, illegal length etc.

I'm not sure how to proceed here and what would be the correct way to encrypt large data. Here is the code used to generate the key and encrypt the data:

```
KeyGenParameterSpec parameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
  ALIAS,
  KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
  .setBlockModes(BLOCK_MODE)
  .setEncryptionPaddings(PADDING)
  .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
  .build();
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
keyGenerator.init(parameterSpec);

SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(plainData);
```

Comment: **Cipher.doFinal() trims data size...** no it doesn't. You have some other bug in your program.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion as what it could be? I'll update the question with some code.

Comment: I have used AES in Android and I've never experienced this problem. Are you sure the input is 200K?

Comment: The input is byte array with around 270000 bytes. The output of cipher is around 70000. I've tested it on this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ConfirmCredential as well, and it didn't work either.